# calculating SNR from dbfs (using spectrograms)

Tags: spectrogram, snr, dbfs

I've the spectrogram of both noise and signal (both 5 seconds). Below image shows an example of the signal spectrogram:

[image]

The colour of the spectrogram shows the intensity in **dbfs (from 0 dbfs to -120 dbfs)**. Now, I'd like to calculate the **SNR** value from these two spectograms. But, I'm not sure how to do it. What I did is:

1. `dbfs_new(x) = dbfs(x) + 120 where x is the value of each pixel (between 0dbfs and -120 dbfs).`

This makes sure that higher intensity has higher value and not lower value.

2. calculated RMS for both signal and noise using their spectrogram:

   `RMS_signal = (SUM(dbfs_new(x)^2)/m)^.5 where m is the total number of pixels
    RMS_noise = (SUM(dbfs_new(x)^2)/m)^.5 where m is the total number of pixels`

and, finally:

3. `SNR = RMS_signal - RMS_noise (in dbfs)`

But, I'm not sure what I've done is correct! Can I calculate SNR from dbfs? If not what do I need to do?

Appreciate your help.
Thanks

Comment: Depends on your signal model. You're assuming you know the pixels that belong to noise and the pixels that belong to signal. WLOG, that's usually not the case.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've trained an AI model that separates speech from noise.  Now, I want to calculate SNR from the separated spectrograms of signal and noise. Could you please let me know that what I've done (the equations above) is right or not? I'm an AI person with little knowledge in DSP and now I need help from DSP experts :)

Comment: Well, yeah, if you've got a spectrogram that assigns certain pixels to signal, sure, then you have the signal power being the sum  of these spectrogram bins, and the noise power the overall spectrogram's power (sum of all bins). Usuually, spectrograms are power, not amplitude, but that's really up to how you display that – also, conversion from amplitude to power really is just squaring linear values, or multiplying logarithmic values (if you haven't, read up on what dB is) with 2.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for the comment. In my case, pixel values are representing magnitude in dbfs. My question is, can I calculate SNR with the above 3 equations? In other words, are those 3 equations are correct? If not, what should I do? should I convert dbfs to db first? I know how to convert watt to db and vice versa but I don't know how to convert dbfs to db or watt!

Comment: I've answered that in my last comment.

Comment: Thanks @MarcusMüller. I understand that if the bin is power we can use it and if it is amplitude we need to convert it to power. But, my question is mainly about **dbfs**. I haven't seen any **SNR** formula that is based on **dbfs**. When it is in **db** the equation is `SNR (db) = Psignal (db) - Pnoise (db)`. When it is **Watt** the equation is `SNR (w) = Psignal (w) / Pnoise(w)`. I assumed that `SNR (dbfs) = Psignal (dbfs) - Pnoise(dbfs)` based on the definition of **dbfs**. But, I'm not **100% sure**. That's what I'm really looking after. Can I work with **dbfs** the same as **db**?!